# Which is the correct method to find simultaneous limit and why?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I tried finding the simultaneous limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ for the function

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}& (x, y)\neq (0, 0) \\ 0& (x, y) = (0, 0) \end{cases}$$ using [the method @alfriedman suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2427600/400242).

Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$.

We get $$f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))=\begin{cases} \frac{r^4\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{(r\cos(\theta))^6+(r\sin(\theta))^2},& r\neq 0 \\ 0& r=0 \end{cases}$$

---

### Method I: (Take $r\to 0$ and then fix $\theta$)

As we take 
$r\to 0$, we get the limit as $\frac{0}{\sin^2(\theta)}$.

The limit wouldn't exist if $\sin(\theta)=0$ (say for $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$). This is the reason why the simultaneous limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ doesn't exist.

---

### Method 2: (Fix $\theta$ first and then take $r\to 0$)

Let us consider $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$.

In that case the limit is $0$ (as $r\to 0$)

Also, for any other angle $\theta=\theta_o$ such that $\theta_0 \in [0,2\pi)-\{0,\pi\}$

The limit is surely $0$ as $r\to 0$.

---

Hence we see that method 1 tells us that the simultaneous limit doesn't exist as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ but method 2 tells us that it does exist. Now, I checked it on Wolfram Alpha that the simultaneous limit doesn't exist. So, I'd like to know **why** method 1 is correct and method 2 is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: What's “iterated limit”? That sounds to me like first letting $y\to 0$ and then $x\to 0$, or the other way around. Do you mean simply the limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry. You are right. I corrected it. Can you answer the question now?

Comment: The limit does not exist is equivalent to that there are several different accumulation points. But your argument is not correct, since in each step you get zero so your limit is also zero. And $\theta$ does not need to converge.

Comment: What do you mean by convergence of $\theta$ ? I just said that if $\sin(\theta)\neq 0$ the double limit exists, or else it doesn't. Of course it wouldn't exist for $y=x^3$ as the derivative is $3x^2$ which equals $0$ at origin. We are basically making the circle's radius smaller and smaller as $r\to 0$ along direction $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$ (I already mentioned that the derivative of $y=x^3$ is $0$ at origin which implies we approach along $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$). @Cuteboy

Comment: @Blue If limit does exist, then it must be unique. The point is, you can not consider $\theta$ isolated after you put the thing to limit. Indeed, you should also consider $\theta$ even before you put your expression to limit.

Comment: @Cuteboy I did mention that the double limit won't exist here as for $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$ the limit doesn't exist. If for all possible $\theta$ the limit existed, only then would the double limit or simultaneous limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ hold.

Comment: The limit does exist even if $\theta=0$, since your first expression becomes $0/r^6$, so the limit is $0$ when $r$ goes to zero. That is why I said we can not consider the $\theta$ seperately.

Comment: @Cuteboy Read my sentence carefully. I wrote it doesn't exist for $\theta=0$ and for $\theta=\pi$.

Comment: We are talking about limit. Your mistake is you take $r\rightarrow 0$ and then you consider $\sin \theta=0$. In fact you can not do this for getting a limit, you should first discuss $\sin \theta=0$, then let $r$ go to zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65521/discussion-between-blue-and-cuteboy).

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=x^3$ and $x\neq 0$, then the first equality becomes constant $1/2$, so in fact the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Ok. Then what is the general method to find the double limit as a function of $\theta$ in that case. According to what I did, the double limit or simultaneous limit comes out be $0$ whenever $\sin(\theta)\neq 0$. But that seems wrong now.

Comment: There is no limit in this case. The general method is, if you are sure that the convergence exists, then use the definition to show that the distance of your presentation and the convergence is getting smaller if $(x,y)$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you use polar coordinated to compute a limit then:

If the limit depends on the values of $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ then does not exist.

In other words if different values of $\theta$ give you different results then the limit does not exist because the uniqueness of the limit is a necessary condition for its existence.

For a limit to exist in polar coordinates,it must have the same result $\text{for all}$ $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

So  the limit cannot exist even if it gives the same result for every $\theta \neq 0,\pi$